# Need to pull Graph API JSON and successively narrow my results

Tags: javascript, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Need to pull from the end point "fb_page_categories" which returns an array of all categories a page could fall under. Which looks like so:

```
GET graph.facebook.com
  /fb_page_categories?
```

This returns something like so:

```
    {
 "data": [
{
  "name": "Interest",
  "fb_page_categories": [
    {
      "name": "Literary Arts",
      "id": "856055631167537"
    },
    {
      "name": "Performance Art",
      "id": "756092301147942"
    },
    {
      "name": "Performing Arts",
      "id": "1758092431143387"
    },
```

I then need to pull all of the results of certain specific "categories" that querying said end point returned, and finally filter those categories by proximity to current location. I'm new to java and have no idea where to even begin, or what that code would look like. Any advice, articles, Stack questions, Git projects, etc that can point me in the correct direction would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You should go through the documentation for Graph API, try out some code yourself and then post it here if it doesn't work.

Comment: Fixed to show what I'm talking about! First time using this platform, thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook’s own Graph search for places can do this in a fashion. On Facebook your current location is implicit with being logged in.

First you should be aware that the list of page categories you referenced don’t all allow location. Only categories within the business and organization trees do so. (Facebook refers to this organization as a category taxonomy.)

For example, the ID for Restaurant is currently 273819889375819. So the search result for restaurants nearby would be found at [this link](http://facebook.com/search/273819889375819/places/).

Graph query for places on Facebook has many other modifiers and it appears there has been continuing development of this feature. After a significant splash a few years ago it appears they have stepped back from fully documenting its use.